# WebDriver get time to load element using implicitlyWait

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm looking for solution to get time to click on element using implicitlyWait in WebDriver (Java)

Example:
Let's say I will start WebDriver with implicitlyWait = 30 seconds

Afterwards:
webElement.click();

Method click() will wait for element, 30 seconds, and when element will be visible and ready to click->WebDriver will click on it, but how we can take time that WebDriver spend to click on element, any ideas how I can get this value without using any Watch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally, the implicit wait just calls the `findElement()` over and over again discarding any `ElementNotFoundException`s until there is an element returned or the time runs out.

You could write your own `findElementImplicitlyWait()` by doing just that - it's far from perfect, but it should do the trick.

1. Set your `implicitlyWait` to 0.
2. create a new `newFindElement()` method that calls the `findElement()` until it returns an element without throwing an exception or until 30 seconds run out.
3. Use the time to your liking.

The code below (hopefully compilable =) ) tries to do that and sout the waiting time.

```
private static final long WAIT_TIME = 30000;

public WebElement findElement(final By by) {
    WebElement elem = null;
    long targetTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + WAIT_TIME;
    do {
        try {
            elem = driver.findElement(by);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException ignored) {
            // nothing to do, element not found
        }
    } while ((elem == null) && (System.currentTimeMillis() < targetTime));
    if (elem == null) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("No such element found: " + by);
    }
    System.out.println("Waited for " + (targetTime - System.currentTimeMillis()) + " ms.");
    return elem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `implicitlyWait` is mostly used for waiting for elements to show up when they're not available for `findElement()`. The click will then be instant (or I just can't come up with any reason why it should wait). So this is ok, isn't it?

```
WebElement elem = findElement(By.id("whatever"));
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
elem.click();
System.out.println("The click and consecutive page load took: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms.");
```

Comment: You're absolutely right about usage of implicitlyWait, but I'm asking: is there functionality to get time of element to wait without any timers? e.g somehow get time from implicitlyWait functionality? Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Nothing better than my new answer, I'm afraid. =/